# Is there a way to add CMS block inside of the description tab on product page

Tags: magento-1.9, product, view

I see many posts about creating a custom CMS tab on product page.
However is there a way to add cms block under existing tab (description)?

Answer (score 0):

Copy file `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/description.phtml` in your theme and add static block using below code at the desired location.

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('your_identifier')->toHtml() ?>
```